# Зачем при создании метода писать имя класса?

Tags: c#

Все никак не могу понять, зачем при создании метода пишут имя класса?

Вот пример ниже, как в методе *CreateObject()* абстрактного класса *AbstractClass*. Его здесь еще называют статическим фабричным методом.

Из этого рождается второй вопрос: **фабричный метод** это и есть метод возле которого пишется имя класса или это **паттерн проектирования**?

```
abstract class AbstractClass
{
    // Статический фабричный метод.
    public static AbstractClass CreateObject()
    {
        return new ConcreteClass();
    }

    public abstract void Method();
}

 class ConcreteClass : AbstractClass
{
    public override void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        AbstractClass instance = AbstractClass.CreateObject();
        instance.Method();

        // Delay.
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: [Фабричный метод (шаблон проектирования)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))

Comment: @tym32167 `CreateObject(out AbstractClass ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static AbstractClass CreateObject()
{
```

Имя класса `AbstractClass` в данном случае - это тип возвращаемого значения. Как, например, `string` в методе

```
public static string getSomeString() 
{
  return "some string";
}
```

который возвращает строку.

Прямого отношения к "фабричности" метода это не имеет.

Comment: Благодарю за Ваш ответ!

Comment: @RuslanKordik На здоровье. Успехов!